# Print information stored in arrays of characters in alphabetic order

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

In a file I have names, surnames and addresses of different people stored in an array. This array is of type Person (a struct) which consists of two character arrays, one for the name and surname and one for the address. I have managed to display the people in the screen but now I have to put them in an alphabetic order from their surname.

In the code shown below I have made first found the index of where the first element of the surname and saved them in an array. Then I have created another array where I have stored the first characters of the surname. After that I have made a for loop and compared the first  letters on the array with an if statement and made the bubble sort. Unfortunately, after I printed the people's name/surname and address they were not sorted properly.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>

#include<math.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>

#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct Person {
    char name[30];
    char address[50];
};

typedef struct Person Person;

//to find in only for one person
//only for one individual

int getSurnameIndex(Person people )
{
    int count=0; //to keep track in what character we are
    int len=strlen(people.name);
    int surnameIndex=0;

    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(people.name[i]== ' ')
        {
            surnameIndex=count+1; //surname comes one character after the space
        }
        count++;
    }

    return(surnameIndex);
}

int main()
{

    ifstream a1("a1.txt");

   Person people[20];
    int numPeople=0;

    int i=0; //we can use numPeople because is the same thing but only because we are used with for(int i=0;...) will put i on there

    while(!a1.eof())
    {
        a1.getline(people[i].name, 30);
        a1.getline(people[i].address, 50);
        a1.get();
        i++;
        numPeople++;
    }

    cout<<"The number of people in the file is "<<numPeople<<"."<<endl<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<numPeople;i++)
    {
        cout<<people[i].name<<endl<<people[i].address<<endl<<endl;
    }

    //now how to print the letter of surname


    int surnameIndex=getSurnameIndex(people[0]);

    cout<<"The index for the first person is: "<< surnameIndex<<endl;

    //now to make if for all the people and store the indexes on an array

    int surnameIndexes[20];

    cout<<"Here are the indexes of of the people stored in the array:" <<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<numPeople;i++)
    {
        surnameIndexes[i]=getSurnameIndex(people[i]);
        cout<<surnameIndexes[i]<<endl;
    }

    // here we store the first letters of surnames into a char array
    char surnameLetter[20];

    for(int i=0;i<numPeople;i++)
    {
        surnameLetter[i]=people[i].name[surnameIndexes[i]];
    }

    cout<<endl<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<numPeople;i++)
    {
        cout<<surnameLetter[i]<<endl;
    }

    //now comparing the letters and bubble bobble sort
    //this is not sorting properly

    for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<6;j++)
        {
            if(surnameLetter[i-1] > surnameLetter[i])
            {
                Person temp;
                temp=people[i-1];
                people[i-1]=people[i];
                people[i]=temp;

                char tempChar;
                tempChar=surnameLetter[i-1];
                surnameLetter[i-1]=surnameLetter[i];
                surnameLetter[i]=tempChar;
            }
        }
    }


    for(int i=0;i<numPeople;i++)
    {
        cout<<people[i].name<<endl<<people[i].address<<endl<<endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Example input and output please.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is at the bubble sort on the if statement. The if statement should compare the "j" element of that array and not the "i". The working code is:

```
for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<6;j++)
        {
            if(surnameLetter[j-1] > surnameLetter[j])
            {
                Person temp;
                temp=people[j-1];
                people[j-1]=people[j];
                people[j]=temp;

                char tempChar;
                tempChar=surnameLetter[j-1];
                surnameLetter[j-1]=surnameLetter[j];
                surnameLetter[j]=tempChar;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The two `for` loops in your sorting algorithm are only going up to 6 when it should be to `numPeople`.  Also, you can cut the computation of bubble sort in half by decreasing the range of the second loop each iteration:

```
for(int i = 1; i < numPeople; i++) 
    for(int j = 1; j < numPeople-i+1; j++) 
        if(people[j-1] > people[j])
            swap(people[j-1],people[j])
```

Comment: I tried but it does not work. I have to compare the surnames of the people's information and not all the variable people. I think my code has something to do with the comparison or swapping that is not working properly.

Comment: Yeah my bad, it should be `if(surnameLetter[i-1] > surnameLetter[i])` not `if(people[j-1] > people[j])`.  The swapping looks find to me.

Comment: yes I checked it again and found my mistake. In my code on the if statement I have put the variable i instead of j. I am so bad :P.